# How to set NOT clause on Date range query in Solr

Tags: solr

Have been trying to understand this for a while ...

How can I specify NOT clause in the following query?

{!field f=schedule op=Intersects}[2016-08-26T12:30:00Z TO 2016-08-26T18:30:00Z]

{!field f=schedule op=Contains}[2016-08-26T12:30:00Z TO 2016-08-26T18:30:00Z]

Like, without LocalParams, we can specify -DateField:[2016-08-26T12:30:00Z TO 2016-08-26T18:30:00Z] to get an equivalent NOT clause. But, I need a NOT Contains Date Range query.

I have tried a few options but I end up getting parsing errors. Surely there must be some obvious way I am missing.

Comment: Try this syntax: -{!field f=schedule op=Contains v='[2016-08-26T12:30:00Z TO 2016-08-26T18:30:00Z]'}    Source: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/lucene/java-dev/326269

Comment: op param is not working for me.
Could you let me know how to turn on this feature?